# Facebook search scrape

Tags: web-scraping

I want help regarding how i can save Facebook data from search results.

I have 1000 query URLs like:

- https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=name
- https://www.facebook.com/search/people/?q=mobile

How can I quickly scrape data from the resulting web pages?

I have tried to scrape with some scraper programs but could not get them to work. Does anyone have a faster way?

Comment: let us know what have you tried and worked. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use python requests library. It is pure and fast library. Scraping speed is not only dependent on your code, it also depends on the web site you are scraping.